# Symfony 3 Database Join

Tags: database, symfony, join

I need a result with all the entries of two tables. 
With this SQL Statement I get my wished result, but how can I archieve this in symfony?

In my result i want to connect dataset.id with datasetFile.dataset_id
how can i get it with maybe join in symfony 3.

> ```
> Select *
> from dataset
>     LEFT JOIN dataset_file ON dataset.id=dataset_file.dataset_id
> ```

class Dataset

...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="strap_id", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $strap_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
 */
protected $user_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date")
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
protected $start_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
protected $end_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
 */
protected $status;
```

...

DatasetFile

...

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dataset")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dataset_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $dataset;
```

...

Answer (score 0):

This is an inverse relationship as I understand. Try to add `inversedBy` in the `$dataset` annotation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dataset", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dataset_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $dataset;
```

The `$dataset` property is an instance of `Dataset`. The `DatasetFile` entity should have setter and getter for `$dataset` like following.

```
 /**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dataset", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dataset_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $dataset;

/**
 * DatasetFile constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return DatasetFile
 */
public function setId(int $id): DatasetFile
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Dataset
 */
public function getDataset(): Dataset
{
    return $this->dataset;
}

/**
 * @param Dataset $dataset
 *
 * @return DatasetFile
 */
public function setDataset(Dataset $dataset): DatasetFile
{
    $this->dataset = $dataset;

    return $this;
}
```

Use this property like

```
/**
 * @param DatasetFile $datasetFile
 *
 */
public function doSomthing (DatasetFile $datasetFile): void
{
    /** @var Dataset $dataset */
    $dataset = $datasetFile->dataset;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: How can I create my query and get the results?

Comment: @user3241084 , I updated the answer. The Doctrine creates the query and the creates the object.